# Null Pointer exeception handler

Tags: java, android

I have made a this function in FourActivity Class:

```
public int getRandomNumber(){
    Random rnd=new Random();
    int randomNumber=rnd.nextInt(100);


    if (randomNumber%2==1){
        randomNumber=randomNumber+1;
        return randomNumber;

    }

    else return randomNumber;
}
```

i am trying to Access this method in another class through this way. But it throws a **`java.lang.NullPointerException`**:

```
int randomNumber;
FourActivity fourActivity;
randomNumber= fourActivity.getRandomNumber();

Toast.makeText(FinalActivity.this,"Random Number is"+randomNumber ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Simple advice. When you get a nullpointer, like this, place a debug mark before the exception occurs, step through each line and look at what it is that is null.

Comment: initialize fourActivity  in your class. i.e. FourActivity fourActivity = new FourActivity();

Answer (score 1):

`fourActivity` is not instantiated, that's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

If this is really an activity, you shouldn't be using it like that, instead create and use a static method:

```
FourActivity.getRandomNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forget to create instance of `FourActivity`

Otherwise the method should be `static` like following

```
public static int getRandomNumber(){
    Random rnd=new Random();
    int randomNumber=rnd.nextInt(100);


    if (randomNumber%2==1){
        randomNumber=randomNumber+1;
        return randomNumber;

    }

    else return randomNumber;
}
```

& invoke it as

```
int randomNumber;
randomNumber= fourActivity.getRandomNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it

```
int randomNumber;
FourActivity fourActivity = new FourActivity();
randomNumber= fourActivity.getRandomNumber();

Toast.makeText(FinalActivity.this,"Random Number is"+randomNumber ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

because you didnt [instantiate](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/instantiation) your `fourActivity`:

```
FourActivity fourActivity = new FourActivity();
```

but if your function was static you could use it like this:

```
FourActivity.getRandomNumber();
```

Comment: Thank you error is removed . Now solve a new Problem. suppose i have been generated a random number is  50 and i want to store a half of it in Integer.I am doing through this Way :         public int getAnswer(int randomNumber){  return int answer=randomNumber/2;     }    but the answer is wrong. why this????

Comment: @user3537259 it is not a problem, it is a some simple mistake, I think it's better for you to debug your code, instead of asking others to point your problems to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the instance of FourActivity in your class;

```
FourActivity fourActivity;
fourActivity = new FourActivity (<your context>);
```