# Accessing public variable in java

Tags: java, android

I created a `public` variable in `FourActivity` and I'm accessing it in  `FinalActivity` class, but the value of the variable always shows `0`.  I wrote a `getRandomNumber` method in `FourActivity` class which returns an `Integer`.

```
public int i;
i = getRandomNumber();    //
```

Now I am accessing variable `i` in `FinalActivity` class as follows:

```
FourActivity fourActivity=new FourActivity();
int randomNumber=fourActivity.i;
Toast.makeText(FinalActivity.this,"Random Number" +randomNumber ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Before asking a duplicate, figure out your already opened [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940444/null-pointer-exeception-handler).

Answer (score 2):

`i` is not static, therefore when you write :

```
FourActivity fourActivity=new FourActivity();
int randomNumber=fourActivity.i;
```

you get the uninitialized value of `i` from the new `FourActivity` instance you just created.

`i=getRandomNumber();` updated a difference isntance of `FourActivity`.

Comment: i am new in java can u tell me how and where initialize it???

Comment: @user3537259 If you change `public int i;` to `static public int i;`, it will behave as you expected (all instances of FourActivity will have the same value of i, and you'll be able to access it by simply writing `FourActivity.i`), though it's not a good practice.